# Free theorems in C++: are templates inherently ignorant and neutral with their objects of unknown types?

Tags: c++, templates, abstraction, type-systems, type-theory

Famously in Haskell if we have a function without a concrete type we can deduce something about its behavior, for example

```
f : a -> a
```

will always be the identity.

With Java Generics we cannot prove that generic functions have a certain behavior since we can use `instanceof` or the methods on the `Object` base class to work around the restrictions, however if I see a method with the signature

```
<T> List<T> reverse(List<T> list)
```

it is reasonable to assume that the function won't use any properties of the type T.

The type signature of a templated C++ function does not appear to offer any hints about its implementation. Is there any feature, existing or suggested for the standard, that would allow us to write function signatures affording similar deductions in C++? For example, some way to say "This function works for absolutely any type".

Comment: If anyone has a suggestion for a better title, especially something that would describe the problem to someone who hasn't heard of free theorems, I am happy to change it.

Comment: No. C++ doesn't promise you even that your template function will work with other types (except ones you instantiate it with). Exactly because it can use properties of instantiated types.

Comment: I don't see how `<T> List<T> reverse(List<T> list)` is promising more than `template <class T> std::vector<T> reverse(const std::vector<T>& list)`. As per rule of least astonishment, I'd expect them both to do the same thing.

Comment: In C++ this could be a method that reverses each element of the vector and only works for Ts that can be reversed, if I understand C++ templates correctly.

Comment: There will be concepts - allows us to restrict valid `T` and generates clear error messages otherwise. The name of the concept should be more descriptive than T. But given side-effects of c++ functions, they can do whatever they want in the implementation.

Comment: templates in Java are not equivalent to C++. Java is genericity (you manipulate some kind of void* and the container doesn't know anything on the things it contains. In C++ std::list is not even a type, std::list<int> is one. It is not about genericity, it is about templates (you apply the same template on different types). In C++, the containers are tightly liked to the template type, different version share the same concepts and usage, but maybe not the same implementation (which is not the case in Java)

Comment: In C++ there are traits classes, which can be used in templates to enforce requirements about what operations a type supports.   (C++20 introduces (or is proposed to introduce) concepts, which provide a more capable way of doing that.

Comment: @Peter Before C++20 and w/o traits, C++ introduced the `throw()` operator which is a builtin "traits" that tells you about throw spec.

Comment: So if I understand correctly: There are ways, existing and proposed, to constrain the types for which a template can be instantiated, but there is no way to phrase the reverse. So whatever constraint I make I can still never be sure that a template makes sense for all possible classes. Furthermore it is unreasonable to assume any such behavior since templates are a completely different concept from generics.

Comment: Would it be considered bad code to have an unconstraint template that only works for a few types (e.g. the example in the above comment reversing every item of a vector)? This is what makes the deductions work in Java imo, as code writing a generic function and then using instanceof checks to specialize it would never pass any code review.

Comment: @Corinna Even if you did, there are types that aren't classes, or even object types. Do you want `list<void ()>` to be supported? (What would that even possibly mean?)

Comment: There always were was to constraint what types could be used to instantiate a function template, like `template <typename T> void f(T);` can only be instantiated for a value type, not a function type; `template <typename T> void f(typename T::t, int(*) [sizeof(T::m)]);` can be instantiated on class types with certain members, etc.

Comment: Partial specialisations. Typeid. Ad-hoc overloads. Either one of those single-handedly precludes free theorems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. Templates are very ad-hoc. Essentially, they are just macros whose expansion is driven by type information. Whether a template can be instantiated with a given type is defined almost entirely based on the expansion. In fact, it is allowed to instantiate a template such that only parts of its expansion would type-check, as long as the other bits are not used.

Whether the expansion type-checks depends on many, many idiosyncrasies of C++, its syntax, and semantics. Due to problematic features like overloading, implicit coercions, casts, and template specialisation, there is no hope for a parametricity property that would give you free theorems.

Some comments have mentioned concepts. However, concepts do not change this property -- they allow to contrain instantiation explicitly, but as before, the absence of such a constraint does not imply that it works for everything.

Comment: The presence of a concept doesn't promise you that any type or non type argument will **work**, either. It says what should not be **tried**.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. More abstractly, concepts only add negative information about what will be rejected, they don't provide any positive information about what will be accepted.

Comment: There were some discussions to add proper O'Caml modules or Haskell like concepts as an typing interface that could guarantee well formed-ness, it went nowhere obv. It's too complicated to retrofit over C like syntax!

Comment: I've accepted this answer since I feel like it is most on point with respect to the question. The whole discussion helped me improve my understanding, especially how different templates are from generics. They used to feel like different implementations of the same idea but now I am really starting to appreciate the implications of the differences. It appears there is not really a way to tweak templates a bit to achieve free theorems (though in this case it is of course hard to actually prove the nonexistence).

Answer (score 1):

A template is not a normal thing. It cannot be compiled like one, as C++ doesn't have (and probably will never have) any meaningful template concept as an interface and a static contract between the caller and the callee, like a "forward declaration" for a function. Imagine a world where any function is actually a macro (almost like the horrible `#define` style but not quite as ill behaved) and has to be expanded to be type checked. This is almost what templates are.

This is also what makes templates so powerful! Templates form a Turing complete language because template instanciation can recurse. It's an horrible sub-language so `constexpr` was invented to have a clean sub-language for recursive compile time expressions without recursive templates.

You can only reason in term of template instanciation. The "signature" tells you nothing. *Like clean lisp like macros, templates are never properly separately compiled, not even with "export template"* which required a second run of the compiler after linking.

By the way, the idea, insinuated by one C++ standard committee member, that "export template" was sold to C++ experts as a proper separate compilation for templates, as if they were normal non inline functions, is a hoax; no C++ expert ever believed that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean C++20 constraints and concepts: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints:

> Class templates, function templates, and non-template functions
>   (typically members of class templates) may be associated with a
>   constraint, which specifies the requirements on template arguments,
>   which can be used to select the most appropriate function overloads
>   and template specializations.
>
> Named sets of such requirements are called concepts. Each concept is a
>   predicate, evaluated at compile time, and becomes a part of the
>   interface of a template where it is used as a constraint.

Note that this feature is added in C++20 and only partial supported by GCC.

Comment: This is a template declaration type specification of what is required to even consider the template: the compiler will stop early on template declaration, rather than later with a dirty error message in the template specialization process. Like a barrier that prevents high trucks from even trying to enter an underground parking for cars, it prevents some forbidden entries, but not all; you can still penetrate with the wrong type of car in the parking lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is what concepts are supposed to do in C++20.  Of course, all existing templates are unconstrained (except via `enable_if` trickery or similar), so explicitly using an `Any` concept could be useful to document the intent.

That said, C++ doesn’t have parametric polymorphism anyway: there is no single way to manipulate “values” of a completely arbitrary type, since there are no pointers to references.)  Even writing `T()` makes non-trivial assumptions about a type.  The (draft) C++20 standard library therefore provides “generic value” concepts like [`Movable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/Movable) that are practically useful but provide fewer free theorems.

Comment: Existing templates are very much constrained simply by the use of types in by value argument passing f.ex. in STL algorithms: it implies that only value types, types that can appear as function parameters are valid there. Of course this is not as subtle as requirements that can be expressed by other means, but it's a requirement.

Comment: @curiousguy: Of course existing templates compile only for certain template arguments.  “Constrained” here is a C++20 term and refers to an explicitly declared requirement rather than one implied by usage.

Comment: What I meant is not that template function with some template arguments are ill formed and won't compile, it's that *some declarations cannot be instantiated at all for some types*, so they are implicitly constrained w/o a C++20 constrain syntax.